# Replace for loop with map and where

Tags: class, dictionary, dart, for-loop, where-clause

I am trying to remove the for loop in my code and trying to use the map and where function. With for loop my code is working fine but I don't know how to use the map and where function to get the same output. I tried but I am getting errors while creating an instance of class inside the map. I don't know what to write inside the map and where functions.

Comment: Your `where` call is missing its callback argument, and the line is missing the semicolon at the end.  There's also nothing wrong with use `for` loops, and it's unclear why you need to use `where` at all since it doesn't seem like your original code filters the list at all.

Comment: @jamesdlin i am in a learning phase so i want to learn map and where function! my for loop is working fine and i am getting the required result. so i want to get the same output using the map and where. Yes my where call is missing its call back b/c my map function  has already error so i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Adding to a list, based on a loop and an `if`, is something you can do directly with a list literal:

```dart
final List<NewCustomerFav> customFavartList = [ 
  for (final article in articleList) 
    for (final customArticle in customerFavList) 
      if (article.id == customArticle.articleId) 
        NewCustomerFav(customArticle.id, article,customArticle.like)
];
```

That listeral can also be written using `map`, `expand` and `where` in a
few ways, but none will be as direct.

The tricky bit is that you are doing two loops, then the if.
One approach would be:

```dart
final List<NewCustomerFav> customFavartList = articleList
    .expand((article) => customerFavList
        .where((customArticle) => article.id == customArticle.id)
        .map((customArticle) =>
            NewCustomerFav(customArticle.id, article, customArticle.like)))
    .toList();
```

This uses `expand` because the inner `map` can create multiple (or zero) results. That's not something `map` is good at.

Another approach could be creating all the pairs first, then filtering them:

```dart
class Pair<A, B> {
  final A first;
  final B second;
  Pair(this.first, this.second);
}
// ...
final List<NewCustomerFav> customFavartList = articleList
    .expand((article) =>
        customerFavList.map((customArticle) => Pair(article, customArticle)))
    .where((pair) => pair.first.id == pair.second.id)
    .map((pair) => NewCustomerFav(pair.second.id, pair.first, pair.second.like))
    .toList();
```

That more closely follows the logic of the listeral, doing loops over the two article lists, then filtering on the pairs.
It's not as readable, and requires a helper type to represent the pair.

All in all, the list literal notation is *more readable* and as powerful as anything you can do with `map`, `expand`, `where` and `toList`. (Sometimes it just requires you to move more complicated computations into helper functions, which can, arguably, improve readability too.)

In short, sometimes you need `expand` as well as `map` and `where` when converting loops that create lists into iterable method calls.

Comment: Thanks, @Irn for your suggestion I tried to run your first approach but I am not getting the output I am only getting Instances of 'NewCustomerFav', instead of name

Comment: The code only creates the same list as your double `for`-`in` loops. If you want to print the names, you still need the 
`for( final customFavitem in customFavartList ) { print (customFavitem.article.name); }` loop too.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following two different approaches.

`First`

```
articleList.forEach(
  (article) => customerFavList.forEach(
    (customerFav) {
      if (article.id == customerFav.articleId) {
        final fav = NewCustomerFav(customerFav.id, article, 
          customerFav.like);
        customFavartList.add(fav);
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

`Second`

```
articleList.forEach(
  (article) => customerFavList
      .where(
    (customerFav) => article.id == customerFav.articleId,
  )
      .forEach((newCustomerFav) {
    final fav =
        NewCustomerFav(newCustomerFav.id, article, newCustomerFav.like);
    customFavartList.add(fav);
  }),
);
```

`Third`

```
final newCustomerFavListList = articleList.map(
  (article) {
    final result = customerFavList.where(
      (customerFav) {
        if (customerFav.articleId == article.id) return true;

        return false;
      },
    ).toList();

    return result
        .map((item) => NewCustomerFav(item.id, article, item.like))
        .toList();
  },
).toList();
```

`Fourth`

```
articleList.map(
  (article) {
    final result = customerFavList.where(
      (customerFav) {
        if (customerFav.articleId == article.id) return true;

        return false;
      },
    ).toList();

    customFavartList.addAll(
        result.map((item) => NewCustomerFav(item.id, article, 
item.like)));
  },
).toList();
```

You can access the complete source code through [GitHub](https://github.com/BBarisKilic/Stack-OverFlow-Solutions/tree/master/question_72511718).

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, @BBK for your suggestions. I am getting the error that says "avoid using Foreach with function literal".   I want to use the map function is there any way to use that?

Comment: @Luisa You're welcome, I have added new approaches. But I think with only map and where methods, only these can be done.